# Erro ao subir arquivos para o servidor remoto

Tags: bitbucket

Olá. Eu criei um repositório remoto no bitbucket e fazia todas as operações normais via linha de comando: clone, add, commit, push e pull. Salvei uma cópia no pendriver e precisei formatar a máquina. Depois que configurei o ambiente, coloquei o projeto do pendriver no computador, não consigo fazer push. Já apaguei os arquivos do projeto, clonei, mas nada adiantou. O erro é:

fatal: 'git/bitbucket.org:andre_sn/sfp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

O comando que faço é:

git push -u origin master

já tentei:

git push origin master

Comment: Você precisa usar `git init` para definir a pasta como um repositório OU clonar o repositório online primeiro e depois jogar os arquivos do pen drive por cima.

Comment: @Marco Aurélio Deleu esqueci de falar, mas eu uso o git init. Todos os comandos funcionam, menos o push

Answer (score 0):

Ao adicionar o *repositório* remoto precisa conter o `@` entre git e bitbucket.

Ex:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:andre_sn/sfp.git
```

Se o *repositório* foi inicializado corretamente, os arquivos adicionados e comitados, o comando `git push -u origin master` é o correto caso for o branch `master` e o repositório `origin`.