# Qual objetivo do git push -u?

Tags: git, versionamento

Já observei várias pessoas fazendo perguntas sobre possíveis erros no GIT e reparei que em algumas vezes envolve o `-u`. Por exemplo [Erro na Integração Android Studio 2.3 com GitLab](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210623/erro-na-integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-android-studio-2-3-com-gitlab) e [Erro ao subir arquivos para o servidor remoto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108266/erro-ao-subir-arquivos-para-o-servidor-remoto).

Na maioria das vezes a pessoa está em uma fase de aprendizagem em relação ao GIT e procura qualquer tutorial na internet e/ou nem lê ou sequer passa a saber o que significa o `-u` ou qualquer outra opção do GIT.

Qual objetivo do `git push -u`? Como de fato deve ser usado?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
-u | --set-upstream
```

Quando seu branch não está mapeado para um repositório remoto de upstream, você pode usar essa configuração <s>para setar e empurrar ao mesmo tempo</s> para empurrar e, caso dê sucesso o push, setar o upstream como sendo do remoto para o qual empurrou. Se você empurrar múltiplos branches, todos que tiveram sucesso vão ter o upstream tracking atualizado.

Eu particularmente só usava a versão longa, não conhecia a abreviação dela.

Referência: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--u

Exemplo de uso (empurrando o branch `feature-upstream` para o remoto `origin`):

```
git push origin -u feature-upstream
```

---

Caso o que você esteja trabalhando em um branch local não rastreado e tentar dar um `git push`, o próprio `git` sugerirá a você o comando que provavelmente você quer, que seria o `git push -u`/`git push --set-upstream`:

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch feature-upstream has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin feature-upstream
```

---

Você também pode usar o `git push -u` para empurrar *branchs* específicos de um remoto para outro. Por exemplo, tenho um servidor interno `origin`, gostaria de enviar o *branch* `master` dele para o servidor externo `gitlab`.

Uma alternativa mais grossa seria fazer:

```
git checkout origin/master -b master
git push -u gitlab master
```

Isso altera minha cópia de trabalho. Mas também é possível subir diretamente o `master`:

```
git push -u gitlab +origin/master:refs/heads/master
```

Assim eu consigo empurrar o *branch* de um remoto para outro sem precisar modificar minha cópia de trabalho.

Explicando:

- `+origin/master:refs/heads/master`
  nome de um `<refspec>`; o sinal de `+` é opcional, seu formato é `+<src>:<dst>`
- `origin/master` como `<src>`
  indicativo de fonte do *branch*; pode ser um SHA1 também, ou qualquer coisa *treeish*
- `refs/heads/master` como `<dst>`
  indicativo de destino; no caso de um *branch*, ele é uma cabeça de referência, daí `refs/heads`; no caso, eu quis salvar o nome do *branch* como `master`

Os seguintes *branchs* eu subi no https://gitlab.com usando os seguintes comandos:

```
# eu estou com a cópia de trabalho no develop
git push -u gitlab develop

# sem mudar minha cópia de trabalho...
git push -u gitlab +origin/master:refs/heads/master
```

[image: demonstrando que os branchs master e develop foram empurrados]

> Também funcionou (quando já há o branch `develop` no remoto `gitlab`):
>
> ```
> git push -u gitlab +origin/develop:develop
> ```
>
> equivalente a:
>
> ```
> git push -u gitlab +origin/develop:refs/heads/develop
> ```
>
> mas eu preferi o `+origin/develop:develop` porque é muito costumeiro, para mim, esquecer o plural de **cabeças** e digitar apenas `+origin/develop:refs/head/develop` com **cabeça** no singular.
>
> Vale a pena usar o com `refs/heads` quando o *branch* não não existe no remoto em questão. Por exemplo:
>
> ```
> $ git push -u gitlab +origin/feature-des-bounce:feature-des-bounce
> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: feature-des-bounce
> The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
> begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:my-awesome-project.git'
> $ git push -u gitlab +origin/feature-des-bounce:refs/heads/feature-des-bounce
> Counting objects: 20, done.
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
> Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 1.72 KiB | 879.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 20 (delta 11), reused 16 (delta 7)
> remote:
> remote: To create a merge request for feature-des-bounce, visit:
> remote:   https://gitlab.com/my-awesome-project/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=feature-des-bounce
> remote:
> To gitlab.com:my-awesome-project.git
>  * [new branch]      origin/feature-des-bounce -> feature-des-bounce
> ```

---

O [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210652/qual-objetivo-do-git-push-u/210655#comment430730_210655) que o Ricardo Moraleida deixou resume bem o uso:

> Trocando em miúdos: é uma configuração de cada branch local para determinar qual branch remoto vai ser chamado se vc usar git pull ou git fetch sem argumentos. Sem essa configuração esses comandos retornam com erro a menos que se especifique o remote e branch de origem, como em git pull origin master.

Comment: Trocando em miúdos: é uma configuração de cada branch local para determinar qual branch remoto vai ser chamado se vc usar `git pull` ou `git fetch` sem argumentos. Sem essa configuração esses comandos retornam com erro a menos que se especifique o `remote` e `branch` de origem, como em `git pull origin master`.

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida , vou atualizar minha resposta com isso, achei pertinente demais

Comment: Valeu! Termos tipo "upstream tracking" funcionam pra gente que sabe o que é, pra quem tá começando é bom ser mais didático :)