# Configurar git para pasta de projeto já existente

Tags: git

Tenho um projeto já em andamento onde estamos adotando o scrum como metodologia de desenvolvimento.

O git já está todo configurado para fazer o commit e o clone, está funcionando perfeitamente.

A minha duvida é, tem como fazer o clone do git para uma pasta já existente com arquivos do projeto ou tem que ser criada uma nova pasta pasta? Pois quando eu aponto para uma pasta já existente ele não permite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível clonar um repositório Git para uma pasta que não esteja vazia, isso não é permitido.

Se já foi feito algum desenvolvimento fora do repositório, faça o seguinte:

1. Clone o repositório
2. Crie uma nova brach
3. Jogue o código por cima desta branch, se estiver na mesma estrutura, senão, será necessário copiar por cima individualmente
4. Resolva os conflitos
5. Faça o *commit*
6. Faça *merge* da branch

Comment: Por que não adicionar o remoto e fazer um merge?

Comment: Pode ser também, mas não me parece ser o caso de existir um repositório local

Comment: acho menos traumático iniciar o repositório no diretório atual, daí passaria a haver um local

Answer (score 3):

Alternativamente, você pode iniciar um repositório o repositório localmente com o [`git init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

Após fazer isso, recomendo que você faça os commits localmente, até para evitar perder trabalho *caso* dê algum problema ou você sem querer execute algum comando com ocasional efeito colateral nos dados.

Pronto, depois de fazer os seus commits, vamos adicionar o repositório do GitHub remoto. Você pode seguir o [próprio tutorial do GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/), ou então decorar alguns comandos (explicação abaixo do comando:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/projeto-muito-legal-show.git
#              \___/   \____________________________________________/
#                |            endereço remoto do projeto no github
#         apelido do repositório remoto

git fetch origin
```

Pronto, agora você tem um remoto configurado corretamente. Após isso, podemos misturar o seu *branch* local com o *branch* remoto (caso já tenha sido criado algo). Ou então, caso o repositório ainda esteja vazio, só empurrar.

Para misturar, normalmente se usa `git merge origin/master` ([documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) para misturar com o *branch* `master` do repositório do GitHub. Mas você também pode tentar reescrever o histórico, botando **todos os commits** que você fez como sendo commits filhos da ponta do *branch* remoto, usando o `rebase` ([documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)).

```
git merge origin/master    # para fazer o merge
git rebase origin/master   # para fazer o rebase
```

No terceiro caso, você ainda não tem nada no remoto. Então você só precisa dar um `git push -u origin master` ([veja mais nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210652/64969), consulte a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--u)).

Comment: Ai por exemplo, feito essa configuração, quando eu atualizar, ou algum membro da equipe atualizar, eu vou conseguir ver que tem algo novo pra atualizar? isso que está pegando

Comment: Isso que você está falando é rastrear um branch remoto. Se você resolver usando o `git push -u`, eu o branch criado no remoto se torna rastreado já. Se for através do `merge` ou do `rebase`, precisa setar na mão. Um momento

Comment: Pelo visto é  com `git branch -u origin/master`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/4438007

Comment: Tentando explicar de uma forma mais clara. Tenho um servidor já com github configurado. O que eu quero saber é, quando eu colocar no servidor esse commit, alguém que está apontado pra esse github, pegar atualização automatica e meio que fazer o "clone" diretamente

Comment: @GabrielFalieri como você tem um servidor com GitHub? Não é o serviço web que disponível em http://github.com não?

Comment: Servidor github que eu falo, a pessoa aqui configurou o github servidor... acho que n pelo serviço web

Comment: Acho que só criou o repositorio pelo github desktop

Comment: Esse processo de puxar as atualizações é o `git pull`, já é algo bem padrão do git. Quão experiente é a equipe que está tratando com o git?

Comment: Na verdade eu mudei de empresa tem pouco tempo, não trabalhava direito com o git

Comment: Ok, então acho uma boa começar do zero. Limpar a cabeça, aprender correto. Eu gosto do [tutorial da Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control). Também tem na Udacity [um curso dedicado ao git](https://br.udacity.com/course/version-control-with-git--ud123)

Comment: Acabei usando o tsc

Answer (score -2):

se ja tiveres um repositorio criado e um projecto local e queres subir as alteracoes para o teu repositorio e so usar o comando git remote add orig

git remote add origin "local do repositorio"
git push -u origin master

ex: git remote add origin https://fulano@bitbucket.org/usuario/projecto.git
     git push -u origin master

Comment: Essa pergunta já tem uma certa idade, e ela já possui respostas. Se espera que, nesses casos, novas respostas tragam informações _novas_, abordagens _distintas_, porém não vi novidade alguma na sua resposta.