# Erro no Git, não consigo dar push

Tags: git, github

Fui dar um `push` e ocorreu esse erro:

> ```
> error: src refspec master does not match any.
> ```

Qual a causa disso? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tente `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Talvez essa solução possa lhe ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/8997852

Comment: Explicando o `git push -u`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210655/64969

Comment: Outro possível erro é que possivelmente você não tenha localmente o `branch` chamado de `master`. Qual o comando que você executou?

Comment: É possível você postar a mensagem completa do Git quando faz um "git status" e a de quando tentou executar o comando acima?
Se tiver dados sensíveis rasure.

Answer (score 1):

Possíveis causas para este erro:

- A branch em questão **não existe**. Isto pode ocorrer se você escrever errado o nome da branch e tentar dar um `push` para ela.
- A branch em questão existe mas **não existe localmente** [na sua máquina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450896/2387977). Para resolver, faça o `checkout` para a branch antes de fazer o `push`.
- Você pode ter [esquecido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/2387977) de fazer o commit do arquivo antes do `push`. Lembrando que, no Git, não é possível fazer `push` de diretórios vazios, o que pode levar ao mesmo erro também.
- Você fez **checkout para um commit** específico (estando assim [no modo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071296/2387977) *detached HEAD*) e está tentando dar um `git push`. Para resolver, você pode fazer o `checkout` novamente para a branch ou `git push origin HEAD:nome-branch`